# Parsing Tree Structure to If statements

Tags: c#, java, python, .net, c

The attached file represents a tree structure, that I want to convert into java source code, representing the tree as nested if statements

```
STOP_WORDS > 0
| NEXT_TYPE > 5: X
| NEXT_TYPE <= 5: Y
STOP_WORDS <= 0
…


If (STOP_WORDS > 0)
{
                If (NEXT_TYPE > 5)
                {
                                Return X
                }
                If ( NEXT_TYPE <= 5)
                {
                                Return Y
                }
}
If (STOP_WORDS <= 0)
{
….
}
```

As you can see, the indentation level using pipe ( | ) symbols represents the parent-child relationship
You can write this program in Java, or if you prefer in any other language you find suitable.

Below is the text file that I need to convert into If statements:

```
STOP_WORDS > 0
| NEXT_TYPE > 5: 5
| NEXT_TYPE <= 5: 1
STOP_WORDS <= 0
| STREET_TYE > 0
| | PREVIOUS_TYPE > 5: 2
| | PREVIOUS_TYPE <= 5
| | | NEXT_TYPE > 5: 2
| | | NEXT_TYPE <= 5: 5
| STREET_TYE <= 0
| | PERSON_TITLE > 0
| | | NEXT_TYPE <= 5: 4
| | | NEXT_TYPE > 5: 5
| | PERSON_TITLE <= 0
| | | SURNAME > 0
| | | | PREVIOUS_TYPE <= 4: 3
| | | | PREVIOUS_TYPE > 4: 5
| | | SURNAME <= 0
| | | | FIRST_NAME > 0
| | | | | NEXT_TYPE <= 5: 0
| | | | | NEXT_TYPE > 5: 5
| | | | FIRST_NAME <= 0
| | | | | TOKEN_LENGTH <= 1
| | | | | | NEXT_TYPE <= 4: 0
| | | | | | NEXT_TYPE > 4
| | | | | | | NEXT_TYPE <= 5: 1
| | | | | | | NEXT_TYPE > 5: 5
| | | | | TOKEN_LENGTH >1
| | | | | | NEXT_TYPE > 4: 5
| | | | | | NEXT_TYPE <= 4: 0
| | | | | | | PREVIOUS_TYPE <= 1: 4
| | | | | | | PREVIOUS_TYPE >1
| | | | | | | | PREVIOUS_TYPE >3: 4
| | | | | | | | PREVIOUS_TYPE <= 3: 5
```

My problem is I don't find a logic to keep track of previous If statements and when to close them. As you can see each line has many pipes(|) and sometime less pipe and sometimes more pipes. I don't find the logic for it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you forgetting Haskell, C++, Ruby ..and many more ..which language you need exactly?

Comment: Language doesn't matter. You can use any langauge

Comment: This isn't about us, this is about you @AnilChaubey

Comment: @Anil Thanks! ~ Please read this ["Help Center > Asking"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: STOP_WORDS <= 0
| STREET_TYE <= 0
| | PERSON_TITLE > 0
| | | NEXT_TYPE <= 5: 4
| | | NEXT_TYPE > 5: 5
| | PERSON_TITLE <= 0
| | | SURNAME > 0
| | | | PREVIOUS_TYPE <= 4: 3
| | | | PREVIOUS_TYPE > 4: 5
| | | SURNAME <= 0
| | | | FIRST_NAME > 0
| | | | | NEXT_TYPE <= 5: 0
| | | | | NEXT_TYPE > 5: 5
| | | | FIRST_NAME <= 0
| | | | | TOKEN_LENGTH <= 1
| | | | | | NEXT_TYPE <= 4: 0
| | | | | | NEXT_TYPE > 4
| | | | | | | NEXT_TYPE <= 5: 1
| | | | | | | NEXT_TYPE > 5: 5
| | | | | TOKEN_LENGTH >1
| | | | | | NEXT_TYPE > 4: 5
| | | | | | NEXT_TYPE <= 4: 0
| | | | | | | PREVIOUS_TYPE <= 1: 4

Comment: I am unable to keep track of If statements and not able to decide where to close which If statements

Comment: @AnilChaubey: Please add edits to your original post, instead of adding them on as comments

Comment: also, you do realize that what you've posted is not legal java code, right?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget : Yes I know. I just need If statements for the expressions in the file. and I am sorry about anything as I am new to this forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Python

```
with open('input.txt') as f:
    indent = 8
    prev_depth = -1
    closes = []
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line: continue

        depth = line.count('|')
        while prev_depth >= depth:
            prev_depth -= 1
            print(closes.pop())
        pad = ' ' * (depth*indent)
        print(pad + 'If ({})'.format(line.lstrip('| ').split(':', 1)[0]))
        print(pad + '{')
        closes.append(pad + '}')
        if ':' in line:
            pad2 = ' ' * ((depth+1)*indent)
            print(pad2 + 'Return {}'.format(line[line.find(':')+1:].strip()))
        prev_depth = depth
    while closes:
        print(closes.pop())
```

Comment: Thanks . I will check your code too.

Comment: Awesome code. This exactly wat I wanted.I am really very thankful to you..thanks a ton...

Answer (score 0):

Your question is super unclear, but here's a start

```
barometer = 0
with open('path/to/input') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        barometer += delta
        line = ''.join(itertools.dropwhile(lambda c: c in ' |', line))
        if ":" in line:
            cond, act = line.split(":",1)
            print "If (%s) { Return %s }" %(cond, act)
        else:
            delta = barometer - sum(1 for i in itertools.takewhile(lambda c: c in ' |', line))
            if delta < 0:
                print " {}"[delta/abs(delta)]*abs(delta)
            print "If (%s) {" %cond
```

I have to go to sleep now, but this should get you started, at the very least

Comment: Thanks I will go through your code.